# Closest-Point Problem with Divide and Conquer

Tags: python, algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm

I need to solve this problem using divide and conquer. These 2D points are given on a .txt file with ordered by their y coordinate. And need to be similar to this code estructure. So i´m looking for help with my issue. Thank in advance

EDIT: This code takes a list called puntos and created a variable x0 that is the limit to divide all the points the ones in the left of x0 go to subpuntos1 and the ones in the right go to subpuntos2 and then orders the list by their y element and now i need to use divide and conquer to create an algorithm similiar to this one

```
for punto in puntos:
numelementos+= 1
x0abcisa = 5
def cogerSegundoElemento (elem):
    return elem[1]
def sublistas (puntos):
    subpuntos1 = [lista[i:i+5] for i in range(0, len(puntos), x0abcisa)]
    subpuntos1.sort(key = cogerSegundoElemento)
    subpuntos2 = [lista[i:i+5] for i in range(x0abcisa, 
    len(puntos),numelementos)]
    subpuntos2.sort(key = cogerSegundoElemento)
```

Comment: Welcome. Please add your code example into the question as text. We want to avoid external links here and in your case the question is incomplete and incomprehendable without going to the external image first

Comment: Just changed the format, thx for telling me

Comment: You need to explain what you are doing in your code in English.  It would be highly time-consuming for someone else to try and understand your code, without explanation about what algorithm you are following.

Comment: I just edited the code explaining a little bit in english what it does